# Laravel compare between date field and date now

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to compare between date field that saved to my database and current date!

The circle is:

1. admin will add a new career with deadline date
2. when someone fill the application he/she will see the available jobs only in drop down list  ( that its deadline date less than the current date )

so this is the Jobs model

```
          protected $fillable = ['job_name','job_req', 'expire'];
```

this is jobs migrations

```
          public function up()
{
    Schema::create('jobs', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('job_name');
        $table->string('job_req');
        $table->date('expire');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('jobs');
}
```

this is the ApplicationController.php

```
       public function create()
{   
    $dt = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
    $jobs = Jobs::get()->where('$dt', '<', 'expire');
    return view('post.create',compact('jobs'));
}
```

Now when i open application form it doesn't returns any job title, but when i remove where clause from the controller it works well!

Comment: some of your `expire` values in table are in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$jobs = Jobs::get()->where('$dt', '<', 'expire');
```

to

```
$jobs = Jobs::where('expire', '>', $dt)->get();
```

->get() will do query instantly, you must use ->where() before it.

Use ->where after ->get(), you will call this function 
http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_where